# Post archive pages bringing me to a 404 page

Tags: permalinks, pagination, archives

When I try to use `next_posts_link()` and `previous_posts_link()` in my `archive` posts page I got a `404 error` page.

I'm using this permalink setting `/%category%/%postname%` and working well for all pages like `site.com/contacts` or posts like `site.com/category/this-is-a-post-tile`.

The only problem is in archive posts, for test I've set the number of posts per archive by 1 per page and trying with three articles to change the pages.

The paginator is simple this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
</header>
<section class="large-9 columns right-dashed articles">
    <?php if (have_posts ()) : while (have_posts ()) : the_post(); ?>
        <article class="left-icon article" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <a class="permalink" href="<?php echo get_permalink();?>"><h2 class="black"><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
            <div class="details"><?php echo __('di:').' '.get_the_author();?> / <time datetime="<?php echo get_the_date('Y-m-d H:i:s');?>"><?php echo get_the_date();?></time></div>
            <div class="entry"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
            <br><br>
            <a class="button" href="<?php echo get_permalink();?>"><?php echo __('Continue to article'); ?></a>
            <br><br><br>
            <hr>
        </article>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    <footer>
        <?php
        // PAGINATOR
        next_posts_link();
        previous_posts_link();
        ?>
    </footer>
</section>
<aside class="large-3 columns to-right">
    <?php
    // some menu here
    ?>
</aside>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I'va always had mistakes with permalinks and pages, probably I miss some base concept of `WordPress` about it.

How can I do to make it work and let WordPress paginate `blog` pages correctly?

Comment: _How_ did you "set the number of posts per archive by 1 per page"? Post that code, please.

Comment: I did it via wordpress backoffice `wp-admin > options > reading`

Comment: Something is missing. I have no trouble with `next_posts_link` and `previous_posts-link` with the same permalink structure. Something is peculiar about your site. Disable your plugins and switch themes. Try to find what is causing this.

Comment: I've deactivated all the plug-in installed: `Advanced Custom Fields`, `Disqus Comment System`, `Flexible Custom Post Type`, `WPML Multilingual CMS` and `WPML String Translation`, refreshed the page multiple times, but the problem still the same. This is the url I call: `site.com/category/page/2` does it points to `archive.php` or should I point to somewhere else? I'm not using other sub archives.

Answer (score -1):

check your reading settings. The number of post per page has to be the same in archives too.

Comment: In archives I didn't set any number of posts, I just set it in reading setting, do you mean there is another place where I should set the number?

Comment: You said:  > "for test I've set the number of posts per archive by 1 per page and trying with three articles to change the page", number of posts per page has to be the same as the number set in reading settings.

Comment: sorry for my english, i meant I've set the number of posts per archive by 1 by setting it in `wp-admin > options > reading`